# Clearing one form in ajax, without clearing the other

Tags: ajax, forms

Have a chat room, issue is, is that when you submit something, the message in the form box stays. What I want, is for when it is submitted using the button, the message one clears.
So, I added $('#mbody').val(''); and added the id mbody to the form with the message in it. But for some reason, it clears the other form.

Comment: show us your html and js code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the non-existant value of the FORM (form inputs have values).  You simply need to reset it.

```
var form = document.getElementById('mbody');
form.reset();
```

Make sure each form has a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

I'll see your vague question lacking example code and raise you a vague answer. ID's need to be unique - you likely have duplicate ID's or are referencing the incorrect ID.